# __str__, returns the string representation of the counter

Tags: python, string, counter

this is what i've done so far

```
"""Returns the string representation of the counter."""

def __str__(self):
    return self.counter
```

and the output is:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type dict)
```

i would appreciate some help

Comment: What would a good string representation look like? For instance, `collections.Counter` is `"Counter()"`.

Comment: The `__str__` method needs to return a string. You are getting an error because you are returning something that is not a string. What sort of help are you looking for?

Comment: Please show the rest of the code where the attribute `self.counter` is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""Returns the string representation of the counter."""

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.counter}"
```

you can use a `f-string` to implicitly convert it to string.

```
"""Returns the string representation of the counter."""

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.counter)
```

or just call `str` function to convert it to string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).